Android project introduces cpython into NDK, compilation error
I am running an Android project on a MAC computer, and I plan to introduce Python into the project through cmakelist. I can execute Python script files in NDK, but I encountered an error while compiling the project, but I don't know how to solve it.
CmakeList:
enter image description here
enter image description here
cpp file:
enter image description here
Error log:

enter image description here
error: "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc
config?)."

Which friend can help me? Thank you very much
So far, I haven't found any effective way
